# Cypress, Vue, and the ability to do a file upload

Tags: vue.js, cypress

So I'm trying to do a file upload test with Cypress within a Vue application. For some reason the FE developer used label/input instead of a button component. So the HTML code ends up looking like:

```html
<label for="upload-137" class="field-upload>
     <div class="layout justify-center">
      <span class="v-btn">
       <div class="v-btn__content">
        <i class="v-icon">add</i>
       </div>
      </span>
     </div>
     <input id="upload-137" name="upload" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" class="file-input">
</label>
```

So I can get the element with cypress with the following:

```js
cy.get('form').within(()=>{
  cy.get('label > .layout')
    .find('span')
    .click()
})
```

No errors occur and it clicks the element. However...no prompt displays for a file upload.

So I decided to just bypass and input the file on the input. So I added the following to my integration file:

```js
const fileName = "/folder/file.jpg";
const fileType = "image/jpg";
const selector = 'input[name="upload"]';
cy.upload_file(fileName, fileType, selector);
```

Then within my commands file:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('upload_file', (fileName, fileType, selector) => {
      cy.get(selector).then(subject => {
        cy.fixture(fileName, 'hex').then((fileHex) => {

          const fileBytes = hexStringToByte(fileHex);
          const testFile = new File([fileBytes], fileName, {
            type: fileType
          });
          const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
          const el = subject[0]

          dataTransfer.items.add(testFile)
          el.files = dataTransfer.files
        })
      })
})

function hexStringToByte(str) {
      if (!str) {
        return new Uint8Array();
      }

      var a = [];
      for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i += 2) {
        a.push(parseInt(str.substr(i, 2), 16));
      }

      return new Uint8Array(a);
}
```

No errors display. No image is present.

So I try instead:

```js
cy.fixture('driver/jack.jpg').as('jack')
      cy.get('input[type=file]').then($input => {
        return Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob(this.jack,
          'image/jpg').then(
          blob => {
            const imageFile = new File([blob], 'jack.jpg', {
              type: 'image/jpg'
            })
            const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
            dataTransfer.items.add(imageFile)
            $input[0].files = dataTransfer.files
          }
        )
})
```

Same issue. No errors, but no image being displayed. I know after uploading an image additional fields will be required and the file's presence is required.

Since that failed I tried the file upload documentation from Cypress. This however GIVES an error:

```js
return Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob(this.logo, 'image/png')
     .then((blob) => {
       $input.fileupload('add', { files: blob })
     })
```

With this I actually get

> $input.fileupload is not a function

If I try:

```js
cy.fixture('driver/jack.jpg').as('jack')
      cy.get('input[type=file]').then($input => {
        return Cypress.Blob.imgSrcToDataURL('jack').then((dataUrl) => {
          const img = Cypress.$('<img />', {
            src: dataUrl,
            crossorigin:"anonymous"
          })
          cy.get('.field-upload > .layout').then(($div) => {
            // append the image
            $div.append(img)
          })
          cy.get('.utility-blob img').click().should('have.attr', 'src', dataUrl)
        })
})
```

Then I end up with

> Error: the event {"isTrusted":true} was thrown, throw an Error :)

I know from manually testing in Firefox that once clicking on the icon to add an image a prompt opens to enter the file then clicking save appends the html with an image located after the span as a sibling.

So how do I upload an image in Cypress for a Vue application?

Comment: Have you tried using this?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload

We're using a custom command that does basically the same thing, but since we wrote that, this package was created and has been adopted pretty widely

Comment: Just tested. Same issues being applied. No errors, no stoppage. At this point I think the file is being "uploaded" but not appended to the page.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? We use "nuxt-dropzone" and "cypress-file-upload" plugin has no effect on that dropzone plugin. Any feedback is welcome...